# MySQLdb read timeout

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Any one use MySQLdb and encounter read timeout issue and how to resolve it?

Check the MySQLdb project, saw a [patch](http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/patches/75/) already applied, but no document mentioned this, how to enable this option？

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
   import MySQLdb
   db=MySQLdb.connect(...other options...,read_timeout=60)
```

where 60 is the number of seconds for the read timeout.

Comment: are you sure there is parameter `read_timeout` ? please show the documentation where read_timeout is available to function `connnect`

Comment: for folks who come across this in the future: https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/_mysql.c#L570 (undocumented, but available for MySQL > 5.1.12)